# Getting a 405 (Method Not Allowed) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I am creating a web app, where one page I have a user list and on the second page, I have the users details page. On the second page, I have a confirm button where I want to remove that user when the "Confirm" button is clicked with a 200 Status code. However, I am getting a `DELETE : 405 (Method Not Allowed)`. So, here is my code down below. Please tell me or help me fix this problem. Thank you in advance.

> Here is my code.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter : {id: lawyerId}">

    <a class="back" href="#/lawyer">Back</a>

    <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
      Edit
    </button>

    <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">Save</button>



    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doDelete(id)">Confirm</button>



    <div class="people-view">

      <h2 class="name">{{person.firstName}}</h2>

      <h2 class="name">{{person.lastName}}</h2>

      <span class="title">{{person.email}}</span>

      <span class="date">{{person.website}} </span>


    </div>

    <div class="list-view">

      <form>

        <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

          <legend>Basic Info</legend>

          <b>First Name:</b>

          <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName">
          <br>

          <b>Last Name:</b>

          <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName">
          <br>

          <b>Email:</b>

          <input type="email" ng-model="person.email">


        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Services

```
    app.factory('people', function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getUserInfo = function () {
        return $http.get('https://api-dev.mysite.io/admin/v1/unconfirmed_lawyers');
    };

    service.confirmUser = function (lawyerId) {
        return $http.put('https://api-dev.mysite.io/admin/v1/lawyers/{lawyerId}/confirm');


    };

    return service;


});
```

> LawyerController

```
    app.controller('LawyerController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {


        $scope.lawyerId = $routeParams.id;
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userInfo = response.data;
        });




    }]);
```

> HomeController

```
    var isConfirmed = false;
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, people, $http) {
    if (!isConfirmed) {
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

            $scope.userInfo = response.data;



        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
});
```

> App.js

```
    $scope.doDelete = function(lawyer) {
        var index = $scope.userInfo.lawyers.indexOf(lawyer);
        $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(index, 1);
        location.href = '#/lawyer';
    };
```

Comment: Is this correct? `$http.delete(location.href + id)` in your `$scope.doDelete` func within MyCtrl? You are going to append the ID to the end of the current URL and use an HTTP DELETE

Comment: yes. And Basically, to remove that user from the list that is in the 'home.html'

Comment: Have you create an API to support the HTTP DELETE Method? This might be patronizing, but do you intend to delete this User permanently or simply in this view?  e.g. if you were to refresh the page, do you expect the User to be visible again?

Comment: Well, if you see in my services I have a backend api.. if that is possible to remove the user locally. That will be still fine.

Comment: yes, simply the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed your HTML, so you passed the person instead.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doDelete(person)">Confirm</button>
```

You can use this to find the index within the lawyers, then remove it.

```
$scope.doDelete = function(lawyer) {
    var index = $scope.userInfo.lawyers.indexOf(lawyer);
    $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(index, 1)
};
```

---

The issue is your are using `$http.delete` which performs an HTTP Delete request.  This doesn't sound like something you intended.

Comment: When, it removes, I want to go back to '  location.href = '#/lawyer'; ' .. and not show in that view until is reloaded

Comment: You wouldn't have to remove the rest of your code.  Only amend the delete button in your HTML and the doDelete function within your `MyCtrl`

Comment: Can you please see my updated app.js code. To see if I did right

Comment: So, when I put the location.href for some reason it does not remove it from the list. But, when href is not in the doDelete function it removes it by showing an empty page. is that suppose to happen?

Comment: So, you're code shown above does not remove from the list when I put location.href inside the doDelete function.?

Comment: The code is deleting a lawyer, then `location.href` is refreshing the page. So you are seeing a new list of lawyers.

Comment: I don't want that to happen. But, I want to go to that home page after it is deleted

Comment: How can that be possible?

Comment: You will need to persist the deletion in your Backend Code.  You either have to look at your documentation to find the Delete API or implement it.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your answer.